# Reload/Refresh the current view using button with Nativescript angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

How to create button function for reload/refresh in current view using nativesctip angular.

Answer (score 1):

You can link the button tap event to method in the model which will reload the data for you which should be immediately reflected on your view. This should be generic across all the frameworks like vanilla, angular, Vue.